# How to make a java jar file to be a single file executable?

Tags: linux, windows, java, jar

I have a jar file with a main class in it. The main class is already configured in the manifest file, meaning the jar can be executed in the following way:

```
java -jar Main.jar
```

I'd like to make it executable, meaning running it in the following way, without the need to provide any parameter. Windows:

```
Main.cmd
```

or Linux:

```
Main.sh
```

**How can I package the jar into an executable?**

Comment: There's an answer for Linux. Any idea how to package a java jar in an executable for Windows?

Comment: Honestly, how hard is it to search the net for "jar to exe"? There are a number of solutions available.

Comment: @karan great, then it will be easy to answer the question.

Comment: Definitely. You can edit your existing answer and add it in, then self-accept.

Comment: @Karan And deny you the credit? Na ;-)

Comment: It's ok, you're welcome to it. :) In all seriousness though, a single canonical answer would be better because you've asked about multiple OSes, and unless an answer covers both it wouldn't be complete.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Answer (score 3):

For Linux, there's a way: Package the jar in a bash file. Steps:

1- Create a stub:

```
MYSELF=`which "$0" 2>/dev/null`
[ $? -gt 0 -a -f "$0" ] && MYSELF="./$0"
exec java -jar $MYSELF "$@"
exit $?
```

2- Concatenate the stub and the jar into a new executable:

```
cat stub.sh Main.jar > main.sh
```

3- Make the new file executable:

```
chmod +x main.sh
```

That's it! Source: https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable

Comment: You can use shell emulators to run the shell script on Windows as well. Example of such emulator: GitBash and Cygwin.